# What could be the reason for ciphertext sanity check failed?

Tags: ssl, encryption, java

I have a SSL connection made with java. It works fine for almost every client but for some of them I get javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: ciphertext sanity check failed.

This is happening after finishing the handshake and sending and receiving application data succesffully in a previous request. Then when I am unwrapping a request coming from the client I get the exception and fatal error:

```
40: ciphertext sanity check failed.
```

The cipher used is TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA.

The clients that fail are Mac Book and Windows 8 Wi-Fi clients.

I am running java version "1.7.0_25" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15) SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64).

If you need more info just tell me.

Comment: What's at the other end?

Comment: Windows 7 or MAC book Wi-Fi client.

Comment: What Java VM (version, vendor & platform) do you use?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15) SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)

Comment: Do you always get the error or does it only happen occasionally?

Comment: It happen ocassionally but always with the same clients, I have around 40 different clients and only 2 seem to have this problem.